# Parabola Terminology

Tags: conic-sections, quadratics

In Danish we call the two halves of a parabola that goes out to each side from the vertex *branches* like branches on a tree. Is there a name for them in English? Are they just called *halves* or maybe *branches* or *legs* or something else?

I want to know the conventional terminology for them, if such a thing exists.

Comment: [The term "arms" is used occasionally.](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa09/DeGeorge/Assign2TdeG/QuadFunction.html)

Comment: Thank you, @Blue! I did not encounter that before, but it looks and sounds like a plausible candidate, indeed!

Comment: [1911 Encyclopædia Britannica](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/1911_Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica/Parabola) calls it both *legs* and *branches*. However, the name "branch" has become overloaded since then, perhaps less preferable. How did Newton call it in Principia?

Comment: @A.G. Very interesting to learn! I too think that *branch* has so many other uses. I wonder whether *legs* or *arms* is more prevalent. It must be a sad creature nonetheless - either it has no arms or no legs ;)